# Synchronizing an object by using a proxy that overrides operator->

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some object that can be accessed from multiple threads and needs to be synchronized.

The solution that I'd like involves creating a proxy class, overriding its `operator->`, and locking around the call to `operator->`.  This is approximately what I want:

```
template <typename T>
class SynchronizedObject<T> {
    lock_t l;
    public:
    ??? operator->() {
        lock(l);
        // do the operation
        unlock(l);
    }
};
```

So with this I could, for example, easily make a synchronized vector like `SynchronizedObject<std::vector>`, and have calls to `push_back` etc be synchronous.

However, as I've done some research, this is not exactly how overloading `operator->` works, as in my example it would need to return a `T*`, and only after it returns, make the call to `push_back` or whatever method I'm interested in.  Is there any way that I can achieve what I want, without having to visit macro hell?

Comment: Indeed, this would just synchronize access to the pointer. The only way I can think of is to create a proxy that implements all the needed methods, forwarding them to the object instance with the locking needed. But that wouldn't be a template solution, of course, since you have to manually code each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept that leverages the recursive behaviour of `operator ->` to transparently interpose a locking proxy. The proxy is non-movable, non-assignable so it can't be accidentally stored (or you really have to mean it).

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct LockedPtr {
    LockedPtr(T *_t) {
        std::cout << "lock\n";
    }

    ~LockedPtr() {
        std::cout << "unlock\n";
    }

    LockedPtr(LockedPtr const &) = delete;
    LockedPtr &operator = (LockedPtr const &) = delete;

    T* operator -> () {
        return _t;
    }

private:
    T *_t;
};

template <class T>
struct LockWrapper {

    LockedPtr<T> operator -> () {
        return {&_t};
    }

    private:
    T _t;
};

struct DummyContainer {
    void push_back(int i) {
        std::cout << "push_back(" << i << ")\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    LockWrapper<DummyContainer> lv;

    lv->push_back(1);
    lv->push_back(2);
    lv->push_back(3);
}
```

Output :

```
lock
push_back(1)
unlock
lock
push_back(2)
unlock
lock
push_back(3)
unlock
```